# View AGPS setting in Android

Tags: android

I'd like to check the user's assisted GPS setting in Android. When I change the 'location accuracy' setting, a ContentObserver tells me the URI is `content://settings/global/assisted_gps_enabled`. I don't see a constant for this in android.provider.Settings.Global; how do I access the value of this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to read that value:

```
int value = 0;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

try {
    value = Settings.Global.getInt(cr,"assisted_gps_enabled");
} catch (Exception e) {
    android.util.Log.e("get agps_enabled",e.toString());
}
```

[results on Android 8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRm7H.png), It returns 1 (Enabled by default)

[image]

To write that value:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(cr, "assisted_gps_enabled", your-value);
```

This permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>` is required and **this permission is only granted to system apps**

Answer (score -1):

A-GPS is turned on in phones when a user has set GPS settings to "Battery savings" and in order to use it in your app, you will have to add permission:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

in your manifest xml file, if you are running app below android 6.0 (Marshmellow), else you will have to ask permissions at runtime, 
see here:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Now, how you will got to know programatically that user has using AGPS or GPS you can use LocationManager class for that and can pass either `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;` for AGPS or `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` for GPS respectively

for GPS provider, in android settings it is termed as "High accuracy" setting and for that permission required is `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
how to use it?
see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies#java

for further help, please have a look:
for runtime permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
for AGPS
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```